Знаете ли вы такие слова?
Использует ли кто-то из знакомых эти слова?
Полызга́чить, барьё, попозже́е, цветуёчек.
Upd: Меня интересует на данный момент слово "полызгачить". Услышала его в семье, спросила у других, но никто ни разу не слышал о таком слове.

Ни одного принятого ответа. Проблемы с качеством?

нет, просто в моей семье говорят такие слова) и как раз-таки не все из них ищутся в гугле...




лызгать ЛЫЗГАТЬ твер. пск. скользить по льду, кататься на коньках, на колодке или просто на ногах. Лызгонуть или лызнуть, улизнуть, дать тягу, наострить лыжи, ускользнуть, скрыться. Лызок м. уход, бегство. Дать лызка, лызгача, убежать. Лызгач лызгачиха, бойкий, проворный на ногах. (Толковый словарь Даля)




Дмитрий Хвостов.
Два плешивые. Два шли плешивые, один на переди,
Другой шагает позади.
По встречному пути лежит гребенка, —
Передний хвать лызгачь*, а задний там —
Находка пополам, —
Я чаю брат, ты ухватил цыпленка.
Другой в ответ:
Находка хороша, да нам в ней нужды нет.
Друзья не спорятся и люди тамо дружны,
Где вещи встретятся их прихотям не нужны.

А вот у Гавриила Державина не понятно, что такое лызгачь (может лезвие или острие сабли?):  Меня тогда, какъ онъ шествовалъ въ Персiю и заѣхалъ въ здѣшний городъ, отдали по очереди съ нашего посада въ солдаты и представили съ прочими новобранными къ нему на смотръ; онъ, приподнявъ мнѣ лызгачь, погляделъ въ глаза, ударилъ по плечу и сказалъ: «Небойсь, малой! служи хорошенько: въ тебѣ прокъ будетъ.» Полызгачить - порезать?

@Sharon: ни одного это как? Он же всего вроде один. :)

Артем, привет! Я вот о чем.  Это четвертый вопрос участника, а когда я писала комментарий, не было принято ни одного. Вот вопрос 27 марта: не принят, комментариев нет. А когда нет обратной связи, приходится сомневаться в качестве ответа, причем всем.

Чего до сих пор закрыто-то, я хочу узнать уже, что такое полызгачить)

вообще «полызгачить» я услышала от папы. «5 лампочек лызгачат» — «5 лампочек горит попусту». вот так) просто менч удивило, что никто никогда этого слова не слышал, тем более в таком значении, вопрос по сути был создан ради этого слова)

@Sharon простите, не поняла ваш ответ. не до конца разобралась с правилами форума

Всё нормально.  Ваш ответ на комментарий как раз  всё объяснил. //Обычно новые участники не читают правила; я, к примеру, их тоже не читала, когда начинала работать.  Потом уже по ходу разобралась.  И замечания о приемке ответов мне тоже однажды сделали) //  И что еще хорошо, всегда интересно знать, почему участник задает свой вопрос.  После вашего ответа это тоже прояснилось)

Вот результаты моих изысканий.
• Барьё (можно, считаю, отнести к собирательным существительным).
Мне не встречалось, но логика словообразования понятна:
вор — воры — ворьё;
жулик — жулики — жульё;
барин — баре и бары — барьё.
Инициаторами покушений были старые столбовые и промозглые крепостники-дворяне, а исполнителями — мелкое обносившееся радикальное барьё, которое двигалось, как марионетки, не сознающие, кто ими двигает (В. О. Ключевский. Записи 1900-х годов (1900–1909)).
• Попозже́е (конечно же, встречалось и иногда использовалось).
В словаре русских народных говоров:
попозже́е и попо́зжей, сравн. ст. нареч. Несколько позже, попозднее.
— Знаю, вчера к вечеру на даче большого начальника другого холуя застрелили. Пишут, выстрел был хорош, в центр лба залепили. Я хотел попозжее, где-нибудь через недельку, к тебе заглянуть. А новость прочитал, понял, следует явиться, засвидетельствовать почтение да сказать, что дело не мое (Николай Леонов. Мщение справедливо).
— Попозжей, милок, попозжей, — отечески нежно зажурчал его голос. — Не торопи лошадок (Анатолий Санжаровский. Репрессированный еще до зачатия).
• Цветуечек и цветуечки имеются в словарях синонимов (мне не попадались).
— Зачем японцы? — обиделся шофер. — Японцы нам не указ. Роли не играют. А эти — международный комплот. Тайная организация. Заговор. И у каждого, обратите внимание, опознавательный знак! Чтобы не спутать с нашими! У кого желтая кофточка, у кого цветуечек. Ленточка, между прочим (Абрам Терц. Кошкин дом).
